# Url query parameters becoming visibly encoded upon redirect - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am attempting to persist my query parameters when redirecting to a new path with **Symfony2**, however the method I am using appears to show encoded query parameters in the URL...

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl(
        'my_page_name',
        [
            'myVar' => $myVar,
            $request->query->all() 
            // I have also tried $request->getQueryString() with the same result...
        ]
    )
);
```

When sending an URL with query params such as

`my-domain.com/some-page?var1=test&var2=test`

I can visibly see the URL change in the browser on redirect to something resembling

`my-domain.com/some-page?0var1%3Dtest%26var2%3Dtest`

My question here is...

1) Does this affect the actual URL being navigated to
2) Is there any way in which I can stop this and keep the URL looking as it was entered?

Comment: I guess this is probably the effect of you creating an array inside an array. What you are passing to the method as second parameter, is an array containing your `myVar` value - and an array of _all_ the original parameters. So effectively you are passing `['myVar' => $myVar, [some array]]` – whereas you should be passing all the original parameters as name => value pairs as well. You should get the array of original parameters first, then _add_ your new value to that array - and then pass the whole thing as second parameter to `generateUrl`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `array_merge(['myVar' => $myVar], $request->query->all())` as second argument?

Comment: @misorude What if I were to use `$request->getQueryString()`?

Comment: Then you would have only a single, scalar string value to begin with. Any = or &  would be part of your _data_ then, and as such anything _but_ encoding them would not make sense at this point either.

Comment: appending query string can be done with explicitly calling Request::create($url) method by passing whole uri and calling static method with string, you can have look at class on source to get more idea. [Request Class Source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php)

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me @MaulikParmar - I have accepted your answer below. I had forgotten that it was an array of params, despite staring at the log showing me that it was XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is encoding request parameters because you are passing whole array as parameter which in terms gets serialized, to avoid that you need to pass each parameter individually. This can be achieved by merging arrays.

So solution would look like :

```
return $this->redirect(
    $this->generateUrl(
        'my_page_name',
        array_merge(
            array(
                'myVar' => $myVar, 
                'myVar2' => $myVar2
            ),
            $request->query->all()
      ) 
    )
);
```